# how to add elif statement in kivy language?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Have a good day everybody, I want to ask that how to add elif statement in Kivy language.
Here is the code in my .kv file:

```
MDCard:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 232.5, 23
    orientation: "vertical"
    pos: 352.5, 255 + 23/2
    md_bg_color: [200/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1] if app.weekday == "2" else [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
```

I want to add a condition that **if app.weekday == "3": md_bg_color: [200/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1]**

Thank you very much.

Comment: that's normal python, not kivy exclusive... i think there's no oneliner to if elif else.. but you can do a clasic if. Anyways i would recomend you to create a default dict to select your md_bg_color or something like that

Comment: @UlisesBussi thank you very much!! but Im just a newbie so can you guide me what I should do?

Comment: okey i put that as an aswer, if there any doubt let me know

Comment: and please let me know if it worked, i don't have a los of experience in kivy

Comment: @UlisesBussi YESSS IT WORKS VERY VERY COOOOOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i'll put this as an anwer.

1. That's normal python languaje, and it's an "if one-liner"
2. There's no such thing as if-elif-else one-liner but you can use some if-else concatenated
3. I would NOT recomend that.

4)You can create a default dict and access it by day to select your color:

```
from collections import defaultdict
#create default dict and default color
default_color = [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
color_dict_by_day = defaultdict(lambda: default_color)

#add other colors by key as "num"

color_dict_by_day["2"] = [200/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1]
color_dict_by_day["3"] = [200/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1]
# and so on....

#for last call your code block as:

MDCard:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 232.5, 23
    orientation: "vertical"
    pos: 352.5, 255 + 23/2
    md_bg_color: color_dict_by_day[app.weekday]
```

Comment: OMG THAT'S FKN COOOOOL
thank you very muchh for giving me new cool knowledge!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want like this:

```
md_bg_color: [200/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1] if app.weekday == "2" else [0/255, 200/255, 0/255, 1] if app.weekday == "3" else [200/255, 0/255, 0/255, 1]
```